# Can tawk.to title tag flashing drop SEO ranking

Tags: seo

If we are using live chat support, most likely we end up using tawk.to I am using the same for most of my projects but one thing I am skeptical about:

That when a message comes to tawk.to, it toggles on title tag with the actual title tag we are having. So my question is, does that affect SEO ranking?

Comment: Does this plugin send messages to users that haven't started a conversation?  (Like "A rep is available to answer your questions.")  If so, how soon after the page loads would the title start flashing?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller this is what exactly I am thinking, comes after 20 seconds for the first load. On reload it is immediate. I hope they might have different arrangement for bots. But not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chat product with title flashing is unlikely to affect SEO directly.   Googlebot loads pages and runs them for only a few seconds before indexing them.  If it takes 20 seconds before the title starts flashing, Googlbot is not going to see that.

Furthermore, Googlebot doesn't support cookies or other local data storage.  The presence of cookies is likely how page-reloads are detected by the chat.   Googlebot is never going to trigger the immediate title flashes because each page load it performs is with an empty cookie jar and no locally stored data.

Any SEO effects are going to be indirect.  For example changes to your site's usability may have impact on SEO.   Any changes to usability (both positive and negative) from using this chat product may have a slight impact on SEO.